# How to get Jenkins Mask Password variable in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Using Mask Password plugin I added variable in Manage Jenkins -> Mask Passwords - Global name/password pairs. 
How to get it by Groovy script in parameterized section of job in Dynamic Choice Parameter?
(in my groovy script I need to specify password to get info, I want to hide it something)

Comment: so you need to specify the password in your groovy script to populate the choices to show the user for them to pick?

Comment: I try to make git tags selection for users: 'def gitURL = "http:/username:how2maskThisPass@giturl.git"
def command = "git ls-remote -t $gitURL"

def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

if ( proc.exitValue() != 0 ) {
   println "Error, ${proc.err.text}"
   System.exit(-1)
}

def tags = proc.in.text.readLines().collect {
it.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/tags\//, '')
}

tags'

Comment: Does this plugin do what you want? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin

Comment: it's useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to decrypt a password using its hash:

```
hashed_pw='your-sercret-hash-S0SKVKUuFfUfrY3UhhUC3J'
passwd = hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(hashed_pw)
println(passwd)
```

I'm sure there are other ways to find a password's hash, but one way it to look it up in credentials.xml